# Word over a text and an element nodes & line wrapping

Tags: html, css

I have this :

```
<div style="width: 20px;">
  Hel<span style="position: relative;"><span style="position: absolute;"></span></span>la world
</div>
```

And I want the word Hello to behave correctly with line breaks. Eg line break happens between Hello and world and not between Hel and lo.

I found no CSS helping, except `white-space: nowrap` (or `pre`), but this has consequences. For instance if I add a space inside the span it is not used as a potential line break.

Comment: and why you have this?

Comment: because I need to put style on fragment of words

Comment: in this case you can control the html so put hello in a span with white-space no wrap and keep your span inside with normal white-space

Comment: yes but I can have live edits of the text ...

Comment: Could you add a live example of your work (non working version with the line break happening between `Hel` and `lo` would be great)

Comment: Yes let me a few minutes

Comment: I finished updating. I was missing a relative/absolute element

Answer (score 1):

There must be something messing with your line breaks in your CSS since it works fine without any `white-space` rule.

Try cleaning up your CSS and check if external styles aren't changing any `display` or `float` of your `<span>`.

UPDATE

Since you have inline style and I'm assuming you cannot remove those, if your spans are empty as in your current update, you could remove the spans entirely with `display: none`

```css
span {
  display: none;
}
p {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  animation: changeSize 10s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes changeSize {
  50% {width: 5px;}
}
```

```html
<p>Hel<span style="position: relative;"><span style="position: absolute;"></span></span>la world Hel<span style="position: relative;"><span style="position: absolute;"></span></span>la world Hel<span style="position: relative;"><span style="position: absolute;"></span></span>la world</p>
```

Comment: I was missing a relative/absolute element. I updated the question